# Python: counting unique instance of words across several lines

Tags: python, performance, words, counting

I have a text file with several observations. Each observation is in one line. I would like to detect unique occurrence of each word in a line. In other words, if same word occurs twice or more on the same line, it is still counted as once. However, I would like to count the frequency of occurrence of each words across all observations. This means that if a word occurs in two or more lines,I would like to count the number of lines it occurred in. Here is the program I wrote and it is really slow in processing large number of file. I also remove certain words in the file by referencing another file. Please offer suggestions on how to improve speed. Thank you.

```
import re, string
from itertools import chain, tee, izip
from collections import defaultdict

def count_words(in_file="",del_file="",out_file=""):

    d_list = re.split('\n', file(del_file).read().lower())
    d_list = [x.strip(' ') for x in d_list] 

    dict2={}
    f1 = open(in_file,'r')
    lines = map(string.strip,map(str.lower,f1.readlines()))

    for line in lines:
        dict1={}
        new_list = []
        for char in line:
            new_list.append(re.sub(r'[0-9#$?*_><@\(\)&;:,.!-+%=\[\]\-\/\^]', "_", char))
        s=''.join(new_list)
        for word in d_list:
            s = s.replace(word,"")
        for word in s.split():
            try:
                dict1[word]=1
            except:
                dict1[word]=1
        for word in dict1.keys():
            try:
                dict2[word] += 1
            except:
                dict2[word] = 1
    freq_list = dict2.items()
    freq_list.sort()
    f1.close()

    word_count_handle = open(out_file,'w+')
    for word, freq  in freq_list:
        print>>word_count_handle,word, freq
    word_count_handle.close()
    return dict2

 dict = count_words("in_file.txt","delete_words.txt","out_file.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running re.sub on each *character* of the line, one at a time. That's slow. Do it on the whole line:

```
s = re.sub(r'[0-9#$?*_><@\(\)&;:,.!-+%=\[\]\-\/\^]', "_", line)
```

Also, have a look at sets and the Counter class in the collections module. It may be faster if you just count and then discard those you don't want afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Without having done any performance testing, the following come to mind:

**1)** you're using regexes  --  why?  Are you just trying to get rid of certain characters?

**2)** you're using exceptions for flow control -- although it can be pythonic (better to ask forgiveness than permission), throwing exceptions can often be slow.  As seen here:

```
    for word in dict1.keys():
        try:
            dict2[word] += 1
        except:
            dict2[word] = 1
```

**3)** turn `d_list` into a set, and use python's `in` to test for membership, and simultaneously ...

**4)** avoid heavy use of `replace` method on strings -- I believe you're using this to filter out the words that appear in `d_list`.  This could be accomplished instead by avoiding `replace`, and just filtering the words in the line, either with a list comprehension:

```
[word for word words if not word in del_words]
```

or with a filter (not very pythonic):

```
filter(lambda word: not word in del_words, words)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

u_words        = set()
u_words_in_lns = []
wordcount      = {}
words          = []

# get unique words per line
for line in buff.split('\n'):
    u_words_in_lns.append(set(line.split(' ')))

# create a set of all unique words
map( u_words.update, u_words_in_lns )

# flatten the sets into a single list of words again
map( words.extend, u_words_in_lns)

# count everything up
for word in u_words:
    wordcount[word] = len(re.findall(word,str(words)))
```